# Mongodb - executionStats executionTimeMillis way longer than cumulative of executionTimeMillisEstimate from each stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo aggregation with multiple stages and part of the `$match` stage is a `geoWithin` operation across a large set of points.

I was analyzing the aggregation using explain with executionStats and noticed that the execution stats of winning plan had each stage with very low `executionTimeMillisEstimate` but the overall `executionTimeMillis` was massive. I'm talking about ~150 fold difference.

I noticed that the queryPlanner has a rejected plan with query utilizing all minor indexes instead of just the location index for geoWithin, which is what is used in the winning plan. But since the winning plan gets cached I didn't think it should matter much.

But again the difference b/w Time is too large to be just because of the rejected plan construction, what else could be the reason for this?

Execution Plan:

```
{
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 101,
    "executionTimeMillis": 85264,
    "totalKeysExamined": 196,
    "totalDocsExamined": 315,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
            "$and": [{
                    "something": {
                        "$eq": "a"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "other": {
                        "$eq": "abc"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 312,
        "works": 196,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 95,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 88,
        "restoreState": 88,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "docsExamined": 150,
        "alreadyHasObj": 150,
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "$or": [{
                        "location": {
                            "$geoWithin": {
                                "$centerSphere": [
                                    [
                                        0,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    0.0000783927971443699
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {},
                    {}
                ]
            },
            "nReturned": 150,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 312,
            "works": 196,
            "advanced": 150,
            "needTime": 46,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 88,
            "restoreState": 88,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "docsExamined": 165,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": 165,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "works": 196,
                "advanced": 165,
                "needTime": 31,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 88,
                "restoreState": 88,
                "isEOF": 0,
                "keyPattern": {
                    "location": "2dsphere"
                },
                "indexName": "location",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "location": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "location": [
                        "[0, 1]",
                        ""
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined": 196,
                "seeks": 32,
                "dupsTested": 0,
                "dupsDropped": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 85 seconds to examine 315 documents? Sounds like something is wrong with your disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total `executionTimeMillis` includes a few things that are not accounted for in the individual plan, like:

- Time spent planning
  The query planner evaluates all of the candidate indexes and plans to determine which to test.  This can take non-zero time per candidate plan, and adds to the total execution time.
- Lock acquisition
  When planning only a small subset of the index/documents are examined.  Once the plan is selected, it is run to completion to obtain the execution stats.  If Other operations are occurring that cause the query executor to wait on locks, this will increase the total time above the estimate
- Disk latency
  Similar to locks, if reading the documents from the disk is very fast during the planning stage, but considerably slower during execution, the overall time will be greater than the estimate

There are probably other considerations as well, If I think of any I'll add them here.  If anyone else remembers one I've forgotten, please feel free to suggest an edit!